# python and pandas: adding a pct column to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Following code:

```
import pandas
import io

d = """
pid,type,speed
1,a,10.5
1,a,11.3
1,a,12.5
1,a,11.5
1,b,7.5
1,b,7.6
1,b,8.7
1,b,9.4
2,a,11.3
2,a,11.1
2,a,11.4
2,a,11.6
2,b,6.5
2,b,4.4
2,b,5.6"""

frame = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(d))
frame['pct'] = frame.groupby(['pid','type']).transform(lambda x: x/sum(x))
print(frame)
```

`pct` is supposed to be the pct of overall `type` among a unique `pid` value, so for pid `1`, the value of type `a` and `b` would be .5 (4 `a` rows and 4 `b` rows).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas - Conditional Probability of a given specific b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468976/pandas-conditional-probability-of-a-given-specific-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code:

```
frame['pct'] = frame.groupby(['pid','type']).transform(lambda x: x/sum(x))
```

gets you the percentage of the speed over the group of `pid` and `type`. It seems what you want is the percentage of the count of 'type' per 'pid'?

try this:

```
frame =frame.groupby(['pid','type']).size().reset_index()
frame.groupby(['pid']).transform(lambda x: x/sum(x))
```

Comment: Works. Kind of squashes my original data frame but that's probably more my current level of familiarity w/ pandas