# Calculate conditional probability in python

Tags: python-3.x, probability

How to calculate conditional probability p(a | b,c ) in python? where the probabilities are based on frequency of states a,b,c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know `pandas` I'd use that, or just write yourself a function that takes in the points and returns probability :)

Comment: I am knew to Pandas. Could you please redirect me to some link?

Comment: the pandas documentation are good but are not the easiest to read, so I'd recommand running through SO. Here's a question that asks about pandas conditional probability: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468976/pandas-conditional-probability-of-a-given-specific-b

let me know if that helps